# redirect users to the login page

Tags: redirect, login

I create a template page as seen below to check if user is logged in or not. If user is not logged in, I want to redirect user to first login page and after login I want him to redirect previous page.

With the code below, Login redirection function redirects to login page again after user login. How can I fix that code?

In my template page :

```
    <?php
    if(!is_user_logged_in()) 
    {   
      wp_redirect( 'http://....../wp-login.php', 302 );
    }
    else
    {   
      wp_redirect('----------otherpage---',302 );
      exit;
    }
    ?>
```

in functions.php :

```
    function directtorequest( $redirect_to, $request, $user )
    {
        // instead of using $redirect_to we're redirecting back to $request
        return $request;
    }
    add_filter('login_redirect', 'directtorequest', 10, 3);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `redirect_to` as a query variable in your link whenever you redirect user `wp-login.php`. Like

```
wp_redirect('http://...../wp-login.php?redirect_to=your_previous_page_link', 302);
```

In `redirect_to` write the link of any page.